# Python Scrapy - populate start_urls from mysql

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to populate start_url with a SELECT from a MYSQL table using **spider.py**. When i run "scrapy runspider spider.py" i get no output, just that it finished with no error.

I have tested the SELECT query in a python script and start_url get populated with the entrys from the MYSQL table.

**spider.py**

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import MySQLdb


class ProductsSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "Products"
    allowed_domains = ["test.com"]
    start_urls = []

    def parse(self, response):
        print self.start_urls

    def populate_start_urls(self, url):
        conn = MySQLdb.connect(
                user='user',
                passwd='password',
                db='scrapy',
                host='localhost',
                charset="utf8",
                use_unicode=True
                )
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(
            'SELECT url FROM links;'
            )
    rows = cursor.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        start_urls.append(row[0])
    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A better approach is to override the [start_requests](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.BaseSpider.start_requests) method.

This can query your database, much like `populate_start_urls`, and return a sequence of [Request](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects) objects.

You would just need to rename your `populate_start_urls` method to `start_requests` and modify the following lines:

```
for row in rows:
    yield self.make_requests_from_url(row[0])
```

Comment: thankyou for the response. it worked, i only had to change `def populate_start_urls(self, url):` to `def start_requests(self):`. i have marked this as accepted as it's closest to the code i posted.

Comment: How can you do it if you have 22M websites to broadcrawl? I suppose you have to do it by iterationg 1000 at a time. Could you show how to iterate it using start_requests?

Answer (score 5):

Write the populating in the `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self):
    super(ProductsSpider,self).__init__()
    self.start_urls = get_start_urls()
```

Assuming `get_start_urls()` returns the urls.