# Setting spider variable from pipeline in open_spider before start_request is called

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to populate the start_urls from a MySQL database.
In the pipeline I have this method

```
def open_spider(self, spider):
    return self.dbpool.runInteraction(self.get_items, spider)
```

In the get_items method I get the items from the database and set the variable
like this:

```
rows = conn.fetchall()
spider.items = rows
```

But in the start_requests method from my spider the spider.items is not set.
It looks like the start_requests method is not waiting in the open_spider method.

I know it's possible to make database call in start_request but I like to have all my queries done using a pipeline.So my question is: 
Is there a method to set a spider variable from the pipeline before start_requests is called or do I really need to make a database call in start_request?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, you should make call to db in `start_request` http://stackoverflow.com/a/20137164/2207154

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Scrapy - populate start\_urls from mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20118753/python-scrapy-populate-start-urls-from-mysql)

Comment: I know it's possible from the start_request method but I like to have have al my database queries in the pipeline and not in the spider. So my question is is this also possible from the pipeline?