# Web Crawler - Windows Application

Tags: python, web-scraping, automation, web-crawler

I'd like to build a web crawler with a UI that allows a users to input a series of Part Numbers and the crawler would then dig through about 6 URL's (manufacturer/vendor sites) and pull back the Qty In Stock value for that part and alert if it updated to 1+ (often times the parts we're looking for sit at 0 in stock for weeks)

I've looked in Scrapy and tried to implement that on our server until realizing it'll never work on the shared server we use through HostGator since they don't allow the Python install or GCC.

Next option was to make use of the Scrapy Cloud but from what I'm reading it looks like I'd have to manually update the spiders each and every time a different Part Number would want to be crawled for.

Is there a way (either Windows application based or web app based) that I can allow a user to enter different part numbers, send those part numbers to a JSON file (spider) and crawl the "In Stock" value and return it?

Answer (score 0):

You could upload `Part Numbers` as a JSON file somewhere and override `start_requests` method to request it. In this case, you need to start the requests to crawl inside `parse_part_numbers` method.

```
def start_requests(self):
    yield scrapy.Request(http://url_to_your_json_file.json, self.parse_part_numbers)

def parse_part_numbers(self, response):
    part_numbers = json.loads(response.text)
    for url in self.urls_to_crawl:
        yield scrapy.Request(url)

def parse(self, response):
    ...
```

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests

Other option would be override `start_requests` to request it from a external database. Something like [Python Scrapy - populate start_urls from mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20118753/python-scrapy-populate-start-urls-from-mysql)